# WebDav - Get "only" new mail after notified

Tags: c#, webdav

I decided to write here, because I have a problem. I would like to get "only" new mail from Exchange Server using WebDav Protocol in C#.

I downloaded "Exchange SDK" from Microsoft website :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms878023%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx

There was an article called "Using the Notification Sample Application" which I tried to use. (This SDK use "POLL" Method)

Everything was fine, because I used this code written by Microsoft which shows how to use Notify using WebDav Protocol and use in your application.

When new mail has come, I was able to notify user about this and after that I "Downloaded" or "Retrieved" mails from Exchange Server.

But one thing which strongly frustrating me is that after notified new mail has come, I can only "get" for example : "All mails" from Inbox folder on my Exchange Server, but I would like to be able to "get, retrieve" only "new" mail which came on Exchange Server.

Is it possible to do this ?

I read a lot of articles in internet, and I could not find any satisfy answer for my question.

It would be great if I can read for example "a:href" for new mail.

I would like to get the last unread mail...

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like is not easy to work with WebDAV protocol. We had problem with development on Exchange 2003 and at the end decided to buy third party component "WebDAV .NET for Exchange". That makes development easier.

Notifications in WebDAV will not give you HRef, you have to do SEARCH.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But... when I use SEARCH (SELECT ... FROM... WHERE) I receive all of the items which are presented in example folder. I would need to GET only new mail not all how I said in previous statement.